# How to Restrict Virtual Computed columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to restrict a virtual computed column in my sql query. I don't have any idea how to do it.
Here's my query

```
select Distinct(Chief_Complaint), COUNT(Chief_Complaint) as 'No. of Cases
Encountered(January)',  COUNT(Chief_Complaint) as 'No. of Cases Encountered(February)'
from Medical_Treatment
group by Chief_Complaint
```

the column Chief_Complaint is a string

I want to add a restriction in COUNT(Chief_Complaint) as 'No. of Cases      Encountered(January)' so that it will only count the number of distinct values that are January from my Date Column and also in COUNT(Chief_Complaint) as 'No. of Cases Encountered(February)' where the month is February
Is that possible? Sorry for my English

Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will something like this work for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #Complaint(
     id                 INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Chief_Complaint    NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ComplaintDate      DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Complaint
    ( Chief_Complaint, ComplaintDate)
VALUES
     ( 'Complaint1', '20160101')
    ,( 'Complaint1', '20160101')
    ,( 'Complaint1', '20160101')
    ,( 'Complaint2', '20160101')
    ,( 'Complaint2', '20160101')
    ,( 'Complaint3', '20160101')

    ,( 'Complaint1', '20160201')
    ,( 'Complaint1', '20160201')
    ,( 'Complaint2', '20160201')
    ,( 'Complaint2', '20160201')
    ,( 'Complaint2', '20160201')


;WITH cteComplaints
AS(
    SELECT
        C.Chief_Complaint
        ,CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, C.ComplaintDate ) = 'January'
            THEN COUNT( C.Chief_Complaint)
         END    'January_CASES'
        ,CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, C.ComplaintDate ) = 'February'
            THEN COUNT( C.Chief_Complaint)
         END    'February_CASES'
    FROM
        #Complaint C
    GROUP BY
        C.Chief_Complaint,DATENAME( month, C.ComplaintDate )
)
SELECT
    C.Chief_Complaint
    ,SUM(ISNULL(C.January_CASES,0)) 'January_CASES'
    ,SUM(ISNULL(C.February_CASES,0)) 'February_CASES'
FROM
    cteComplaints   C
GROUP BY
    C.Chief_Complaint

DROP TABLE #Complaint
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question.
I already have a database with a table 'Medical_Treatment'.
Now all I wanna do is to restrict my select statement.
That out put I want to have is like this. Assume this is a table.
Chief_Complaint/No. of Cases Encountered(January)/No. of Cases Encountered (February)

Abdominal/3/5

Comment: You've lost me.  Provide a schema of your table then I'll see what I can do help.

Comment: sorry if my question is hard to understand.
Okay to make it clearer
I have a table named Medical_Treatment which contains 6 columns but I will only name 2 because the rest are not that important.
The columns are Date which is obviously a date type and Chief_Complaint which is a string. Every data in the Chief_Complaint column has a corresponding Date. Now I want to count all chief_complaint based on the months in my date column.
The output will be Chief_Complaint, Complaint January , Complaint February, Complaint March etc.
Hope you could help me.

Comment: My apologies I did not see all your answer. I've tried your code and it worked! This is what Im looking for. Thank you! :)

Comment: I have another problem. I want to add 1 more column for the total number of complaints per complaint and another row for the total number of complaints per month.
Hope you can help me again.